# HOLD how to create an associative array inside a fixed length array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

UPDATE: ON HOLD, I JUST THOUGHT OF SOMETHING TO TRY. SORRY FOR MY STUPIDITY
**brain fart**

I'm stuck trying to understand how to implement an associative array (strings as keys, doubles as values), with a fixed number of columns, inside a single dimension array (integers as keys).

```
//outer array:
temperature_stations[0] = [ 
  //inner array
   ["high",25.12], ["low",21.1], ["mean",22.50], ["mode", 23.95], ["duration at mode", 120.45] 
];
```

from what I've read, recommendations are to use a dictionary if you want associative arrays, but it's a fixed number of "columns" for the inside array (i won't need to expand the collection), and i don't need fancy insert abilities, so this seems like the wrong object...

**set and get requirements**

i need to set values for each element
temperature_stations[2]["high"] = 27.59;

but getting results is just by walking through each element using a simple loop

Comment: `Dictionary<string, double> [] temperature_stations = new Dictionary<string, double>[10];` But I would think a class to hold the data would be better.

Comment: There's nothing really that fancy about inserts with a dictionary, but if you want association, that's the type of structure you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want an array of `Dictionary<string, double>` or, if the shape of each temperature station is the same then you can use an array of a specific type like

```
public class Reading{
  public decimal High {get;set;}
  public decimal Low {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

Tuples might also be good for this but I typically use those only as throwaway types within a single class.